# Plotting a 3d polynomial in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, polynomials, matplotlib-3d

I have a polynomial function, let’s say a+bx+cx^2. I show the function in a 2d plot, but I want to progress to show it in 3d. But not just showing it, giving it height, so if I have x,y I set a Z1 which represents the first layer, and then Z2 which means the second layer, and so on,
or, giving a specific Z, which will create a higher(in height) polynomial function and then somehow connect the dots. So in the end, I will get a shape that is the 3d of that same polynomial but with height.
I don’t know how to get that done, maybe because I can't see another way to do it.

If I represent a 2d function for example:

*a+bx+cx^2 function*
[image: a+bx+cx^2 function]

Now if I want to view it in 3d when the current polynomial is on Z=0, how can I show it when it has height.

I want to view it like this but from 3d:

[image: 3d plot]